# Ubuntu 22.04 - graphic driver issues

Tags: drivers, 22.04, gigabyte

I just finished to install Ubuntu 22.04 on the friend's computer ( the computer is a little old, the motherboard is Gigabyte GA-M68MT-S2 ) I could install correctly the OS but after that I have see some problems especially when I select any ubuntu button (see the shared screenshot below)

I already installed all the post installation upgrades executing **sudo apt update && apt upgrade** then I restarted the computer but the problem persist.

I would like know if I have to do any other extra step to finish the setup correctly.

I hope you can help me guys!
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: The screenshot should show what problem exactly?

Comment: if you see at the top you will see the issue

Comment: Which graphics? If Nvidia did you select the option to install 3rd party drivers?

Comment: There might be no nvidia driver if the card is too old. You need to post the hardware specs - CPU, graphics, etc, and not just the board model.

Comment: Hi, I think I solved the problem adding a Gforce graphic board. because I added the board and then I turned on the pc and the unity inteface changed completly, now it looks good! but I would like know if this could work fine without the Gforce board added recently